# 802.11ac Router and Adapter Use 802.11n

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, 802.11n, 802.11ac

I have a [Linksys WRT1200AC](https://www.linksys.com/gb/p/P-WRT1200AC/) running [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) in `5GHz` mode (the `2.4GHz` one has a different `SSID`) with `80MHz` width and a [TP-LINK Archer T8E AC1750](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T8E.html) which connects my computer to the router. They're both in the same room so there's full signal between them. My router is the only one transmitting on channel 64, with the closest one being on channel 48 so there's no intereference.

Because both support `802.11ac` mode, the computer is connected on the `5GHz` network and there's strong signal between them, I would have expected the connection to be `802.11ac`. However, when checking the connection details, it's `802.11n`:

[image: WiFi Screenshot]

- Why is this happening? Is there any advantage of using `802.11n` over `802.11ac` in `5GHz` mode?
- If not, how do I force it to use `802.11ac`? I played with the adapter config in `Windows 10` but couldn't get it to use `802.11ac`.

Note: I have a [Synology NAS](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/products/DS216j) with a [WD Red harddisk](https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-storage/wd-red.html) connected via gigabit port to the router. The max transfer speed I get is 50MB/s, which is 400Mbps, consistent with the typical `802.11n` 450Mbps limit, indicating that indeed it's running slower than it should. The NAS, HDD and router are all rated much higher than 50MB/s.

---

Task Manager performance screenshots:

[image: Task Manager performance screenshots]

Comment: Please provide screen of Task Manager’s network performance view while transferring a large file. 50 MiB/s cannot be achieved with 11n.

Comment: @DanielB - added and as can be seen in the left image, it seems it can.

Comment: Congratulations, you may be the first person in the world to reach the advertised speeds for 802.11N. you really must have NO environmental interference what so ever. Go to device manager, go to your wireless interface --> advanced driver settings. Look for the speed negotiation settings. You should be able to specify AC only here.(if it's available in the driver that is)

Comment: Also note, that some of these adapters fallback to N-mode when radio reports 802.11h events. If your router has the option, you may be able to set AC only. Not AC + N mixed. Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm, it was very useful. I'm not saying I've got the holy grail of 802.11n, but that's what my machine is showing. If it's wrong, I'd be glad to hear why and/or how it can be fixed. I've looked through all the adapter settings and there's no mention of AC at all, nor of the speed negotiation you mentioned. The router is already set to AC mode and there's nowhere to turn off the 802.11n as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Windows` is reporting it as `802.11n` even though it's treating it as `802.11ac` so really there's nothing to fix.

I've downloaded the `TP-LINK` utility and connected to the network. Note the `Rate` and `Wireless Mode`:

[image: TP-LINK Wi-Fi Utility Screenshot showing wireless mode 802.11ac and rate 780Mbps]

I then looked for a second confirmation and sure enough I found it in the form of the very useful command `netsh wlan show interfaces`:

[image: PowerShell NetSH interface showing 1300Mbps connection]

Although this shows the `Radio type` as `802.11n`, it also shows the `Receive Rate (Mbps)` as 1300, which is the max speed my adapter supports for `802.11ac` which leads me to believe it's actually running in `802.11ac` mode but `Windows` isn't showing it correctly.

Comment: Windows only shows what the driver is reporting, so that’s what’s to blame. :) // Also, on data rates: Because WiFi uses a shared medium, it cannot send and receive at the same time. It’s roughly 50%/50% send/receive minus some overhead, so that’s how the bandwidth looks like. You can *never* achieve 300/450/600 MBit/s net throughput with 11n, just like you won’t get 1300 MBit/s with 11ac.